# The precedence of JavaScript as part of the page and the injected JavaScript (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, onkeydown, javascript-injection

In Android, using the WebViewClient hooks, we can inject our JavaScript code into the pages that are loaded in the Android WebView. The loaded pages may have JavaScript code as well. The question is, which has more precedence? The injected JavaScript or the scripts that are part of the page?
Context: intercepting all keyboard presses.

Comment: As far as locally tested, the Javascript, always... but, if the key is not "consumed", then both scripts get the event.

Comment: could you please be more precise (use IJavaScript to refer to the injected JavaScript, and PJavaScript to refer to the JavaScript that is sent as part of the page), what do you mean by consumed?

Comment: Suppose a script that waits for the event (keypress), on a button ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click)), if the button has an associated event, then it will "consume" the event, and whatever is under the pointer will try to consume the event.... To simplify... suppose a HTML page, with a button element and a paragraph element...the button is wired to an action, and can consume the event. If you click the paragraph, nothing happens (and the JavaScriptInterface in the android CAN receive it), should the button be pressed, it can consume the event, and end processing